# Persisting tense backshifting in the "i'd rather" hypothetical

Tags: grammar, backshifting

Today I was discussing something with my boss and I said the following sentence:

> I'd rather we experimented with things we **haven't** tried yet

I said that as a response to an idea of reusing an old piece of tech for our next project. I'm wondering whether this is correct considering the past tense in "experimented". Should I have continued on with that tense in the rest of my sentence? Like so:

> I'd rather we experimented with things we **hadn't** tried yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"experimented" is not real but unreal past, being required by "I'd rather." Its meaning is present. Therefore, the present perfect is fine to refer to things you haven't experimented so far.

Also:

- I'd rather we started experimenting with things we haven't tried yet.